# How do I set up two dlink routers dir853 for same speed from my isp

Tags: router

I got 2 router to increase the coverage and speed at the speed at the same time. So I have connected it lan to lan port 2 to port 2 .I changed the ip address on the second router to the same subnet.I have disabled upnp and dhcp server. It works but I am just skeptical if I didnt complete the setup because I d like to see internet connected with green and check the internet speed from the router itself on the second router. please note there is other options like dns relay and ipv4 and ipv6 multicast and stuff.and internet options like ppoe ll2p dslite and stuff so anything I could change to show dlink supports it as well?

Comment: There is no way to increase the internet speed at the modem beyond that of the ISP plan. There are ways to utilize that throughput more efficiently, such as **(1)** 
 requesting more than one WAN IP from the ISP, then bonding those >2 WAN connections upstream of the modem _(most consumer routers don't support this)_; **(2)** ensuring the modem used has at least 16 download channels, as the modem, _at minimum_, needs to equal the number of download channels available to the ISP (cable modems: navigate to `192.168.100.1`); **(3)** for downloading files, a download manager could be utilized.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

To actually "increase the coverage and speed" you need to speak with your ISP.

The simple way is to ask for more bandwidth.

What you're suggesting above requires *duplicated* hardware from your ISP (e.g. a second optic fiber).

Just connecting the second router will increase the amount of network ports, and likely leave the additional ones slightly slower due to that traffic having to pass one extra router.

Comment: Throughput wouldn't be noticeably slower, as routers can process millions of packets a second.  Throughput might see a few microseconds (thousandths of a millisecond) of lag on the LAN side, but this would not be perceptible and could only be seen by comparing the ping values of a device connected to router 1 and a device connected to router 2, pinging router 1.

Comment: The "in practice speed" would not be noticeably different, that is true. But the intent here was to speed up things. By the NUMBERS you DO get a slight slowdown instead, noticeable or not.